# ios 17 flutter page display white screen

Tags: flutter, ios17, xcode15

Our ios project integrates flutter with pod. In ios17, when entering flutter page, the white screen is displayed, the content is not rendered, and it can be displayed normally on systems below ios17.

When I try to create a new ios project, and also integrate flutter with pod, the flutter page is displayed in ios17 and below

Have you encountered this problem? How to solve it

self.flutterVC = [[MyFlutterViewController alloc] initWithEngine:app.flutterEngine nibName:nil bundle:nil];
[vc presentViewController:self.flutterVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, did you find the reason? My customer faces the same issue that app download from app store with iOS 17.3.1, but I can't reproduce the issue. Our project is a simple Flutter App. And I can't see any report in firebase. Hope you have the answer, many thanks!

Comment: My flutter version is 3.16.5. Dart version is 3.2.3. The page is the first page that in GetMaterialApp home.